# check email not start with number and does not contain special keyword

Tags: javascript, email

I have use this regex but it is not working properly.

```
  function regex(){
    var reg = /^[a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/;
  }
```

for example : 123@gmail.com or abc$my@domain.com  for this it is showing valid email but this is not a valid email

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47155282/regex-for-a-string-which-do-not-start-with-a-number-and-allow-only-alphanumeric?rq=1) might help you

Comment: There are now a huge number of TLDs that are not between two and four characters long and/or are not in the Roman alphabet. I recommend against using regexes to validate email addresses because they are generally far too simplistic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*123@domain.com* and *abc$my@domain.com* **are** generally valid.

Read this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local-part) and this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2049510/10214845) about the structure of email adresses for reference.

Comment: how can $ is valid

Comment: Printable charactes like `!#$%&'*+-/=?^_\`{|}~;` are valid in the local part of an email adress. 
Please have a look at the wikipedia article.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the local part (i.e. before the '@') to begin with a letter by using

> ^[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9._%+-]{0,63}

And if just want to use alphanumeric values, use this:

> /^[A-Z0-9]+$/gi